# webkit transition doesn't fade, just disapears

Tags: webkit, css-transitions

I have a set up where I have three squares, the first two are set up to fade away when the third one is clicked.  When you click it what happens though is the first two just disappear, no fading, I can't really figure out why, any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/6fSEz/

that's the fiddle and this is the code by itself:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box 
{     
    opacity:1;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
} 

#box1
{
    background-color: green;
}

#box2
{
    background-color: red;
}

#box3
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.fadeAway1
{ 
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; 
}  

.fadeAway2 
{ 
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5s; 
}  
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" onclick="box2.className='fadeway1';box1.className='fadeaway2';"   
class="box">Tap to fade</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: if I put <div id="box3" onclick="this.className='fadeAway2';" class="box">Tap to fade</div> for example in the body box3 will fade like it's suppose to, but for some reason then takes up the entire width.  Not sure what's going on here with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click function you are removing the styles applied by the ".box" class styles. This removes the width and height, etc.  Also, CSS and JavaScript are case-sensitive. Capitalization between selectors must match the element attributes, exactly.

Updated jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/6fSEz/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/6fSEz/2/)

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me with this.  In the click function does teh += keep the "box" class and just add the changes from the fadeAway class?  Seems like just = was replacing it completely is what you're saying?

Comment: @loriensleafs: Yes the "+=" operation adds or concatenates the left side with the right side (e.g., i += 1 increments using addition); therefore, the original className is concatenated with the appended name " container_click1".

Comment: one more question, I have this fiddle set up using the same idea, I'm trying to get the top plane to move down 35 pixels in the translate3d, and I can't get it to work using the same set up.  I had asked about this to try to understand the concept and then implement it, but I'm having a hard time figuring this out.  http://jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/3/

Comment: @loriensleafs: Again, the CSS id selector for #planet has precedence over the more broad ".spacelayer_collapse" class selector. Add the " ! important" flag to the end of the style item.  http://jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/5/.         .spacelayer_collapse
{
-webkit-transform: 
                   translate3d(-14px, -80px, 3px)
                   scale3d(0.65, 0.9, 0.95)
                   rotate3d(0, 3, 2, 180deg)
                   rotatez(-25deg)
                   rotatey(3deg) ! important;
-webkit-transition-property: all; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s; 
}

Comment: okay, I have ONE more question, then I promise I'll stop, you're just a great resource and I've been messing around with this for a while.  I got it to work this way: http://jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/4/ , which is nice because of the keyframes which makes it easy to do multiple stages.  Why doesn't the state of the animation persist?  It goes back to the way it was?

Comment: @loriensleafs: Looks like it must be the "animation" versus the "transform" styles.  The transformation in jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/5 works, but the animation on yours returns after animating the movement.  Seems, that the reason the animation gets used on yours but not the transform is because there is no animation style in the #planet selector styles, but there is a transform style.  Make sense?

Comment: so the animation style is what I used in the class that activates on click right?  With the percents.  That does make sense, how do you add an animation style to #planets style which out having it start playing automatically and waiting til the click happens?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8649/discussion-between-fenone-and-loriensleafs)